# Как сделать кнопку, нажав на которую откроется одна из множества ссылок?

Tags: html, javascript

Собственно, нужно, чтобы на сайте, при нажатии на кнопку, открывалась 1 из нескольких ссылок рандомно. Возможно такое?

Comment: Возможно.  Что вы уже сделали, и на чём застряли?

Comment: Соль в том, что javascript я не знаю, но предполагаю, что такое осуществить можно через него... Поэтому прошу опытных специалистов накатать операцию javascript'a, которую впоследствии можно будет приклеить к html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать рандом - генератор случайных чисел.
[Тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) написано, как.

Чтобы открыть ссылку, можно использовать свойство window.location.href